# PostgreSQL functions and triggers update question

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I have 2 tables Book and Borrowings when a student borrows a book, a new row added in borrowings table by the application and when student returns the book, that row which was added is updated by the application.

I am trying to create a trigger to update the book table status field of the row when a new row is entered or updated in borrowings table.

Book - (book_id,book_name, book_status)
Borrowings - (student_id, book_id, status)

here is the function and trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upt_book_status_fn() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        update book set book_state = new.status from
        book a, borrowings b where
        a.book_id = b.book_id;
            RETURN new;
    END;
$$;


CREATE TRIGGER updt_book_status_tr AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON borrowings FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE FUNCTION updt_book_status_fn();
```

I am not getting any errors, but the function updates all rows of book and not just one row. Can someone suggest the correct update statement in the function?

Answer (score 0):

you should **not** repeat the target table of an UPDATE in the FROM clause.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.6)

> Do not repeat the target table as a `from_item` unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the `from_item`).

So the correct UPDATE with a join should be:

```
update book 
  set book_state = new.status 
from borrowings b 
where a.book_id = book.book_id;
```

But this would still update all rows, as you don't limit this to the book that was just updated in the borrowings table.

In fact, you don't need the `FROM` clause at all, because you have the book_id in the `new` record:

```
update book 
  set book_state = new.status 
where book_id = new.book_id;
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the help.